# Nodejs Error EJSONPARSE ERROR

Tags: node.js

```
{
 "name": "nodej",

 "version": "1.0.0",

 "description": "",

 "main": "index.js.js",

"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  "start":"node index"
 },

"author": "",

"license": "ISC"
}
```

when i type npm start i get these errors:

> C:\Users\User\Documents\nodejs\nodej>npm start
>       npm ERR! file C:\Users\User\Documents\nodejs\nodej\package.json
>       npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
>       npm ERR! Failed to parse json
>       npm ERR! Unexpected string in JSON at position 166 while parsing '{
>       npm ERR!   "name": "nodej",
>       npm ERR!   "version": "1.0.0'
>       npm ERR! File: C:\Users\User\Documents\nodejs\nodej\package.json
>       npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
>       npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
>       npm ERR!
>       npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse
>       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>       npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-12-
>       10T17_30_24_632Z-debug.log

Comment: Missing a comma? `{ "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1", "start":"node index" },`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a comma after the test script:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1", <-- COMMA HERE
  "start":"node index"
 },
```

Answer (score -1):

```
{
  "name": "nodej",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: use this instead.